# CSS Transition doesn't work on chrome for android

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui, css-transitions

I am coding a `react` application that displays an animation for a moving color within a div when a user clicks. I do this using a div inside that changes its `inset-inline-start` and that has a `transition: all 0.3s ease`. I am using MUI, so it auto-fills `-webkit-transition`. For some reason, *the animation doesn't show up on chrome for android*.It works perfectly fine in my computer's devtools and when tested on an iPhone, and on my android device with firefox, but not on my android device with chrome...

I tried replacing `inset-inline-start` with `left`, removing other properties like `pointer-events: none`, and more - to no effect... I tried updating my version of chrome, tested on other androids - and it doesn't work on any android device.

Here is what shows up in my devtools:

[image: the devtools code]

(I am using `stylis-rtl-plugin`, which is why the `.muirtl-...`)

The `inset-inline-start` property changes correctly and the box moves, and in the other scenarios it animates nicely and moves from place to place, but not on chrome with androids...

Would really appreciate help - can't wrap my head around why this is happening...